# ReloadData doesn't fire tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, reloaddata

I just encouter a problem, that I call UITableView reloadData method, but nothing happened. No tableView:numberOfRowsInSection is called.

The scenario is:

Table works fine in view A (has the UITableView), then view B shows and hide, after this step, the UITableView reloadData is not working anymore. I am sure reloadData is called in main UI thread and the data source has been changed. Also NO IBOutlet connection issue.

Comment: your question couldn't be any more vague. do post some code or give some explanation as to what you have done.

Comment: Agreed, we can't diagnose what's going wrong without seeing the source code.

Comment: My guess is, If the view B is in above the view A(has the UITableView) then the reloadData won't work, Just try removing the view B from it's superview.

Comment: I tried to reloadData after the view B viewDidDisappear, still no working

Comment: I guess it relates to visibility of UITableView, but it's weird that is still not working after the view B dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your call to reloadData in viewWillAppear.

Comment: why put it in viewWillAppear?

Comment: If your first view (view A) is never unloaded, then viewDidLoad won't be called when you go back to it, but viewWillAppear will.

Comment: That's assuming you had reloadData inside of viewDidLoad to begin with.

Comment: Also, make sure you are re-fetching your data from your data source before calling reloadData, otherwise reloadData won't show you anything new even if it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Set BreakPoint on [tableView reloadData]; check that your tableView object is not nil.